# How to make 93 using only 2 0 2 4

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

How to make 93 using only 2 0 2 4? The digits can be used only once.

You can use

$+,-,*,/,Sqrt,X^y,!,!!,nCr,nPr$

You can also group 2 and 2 to make ‘22’ and you can also use the above method to make 24 220 or .2

By definition, 0! = 1

Comment: You're more than half a year early.

Comment: The as is state of the question seems too broad and can have many answers. You may want to tweak it to add some rules to it.

Comment: But I use like 6hrs at school and still didn’t find one

Comment: @Erniewong Do you want solvers to use the digits only once?

Comment: @Bass Or super late for 2024 B. C.

Comment: @Erniewong, since you mention school, how old are you? And you can merge your accounts, see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That will give you owner's control over this question, which includes edits, comments, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it

> $$ \left[\left(\left(\sqrt{!4} \right)!\right)!!\times 2\right] - 2 - 0! = 93$$

where we have used

> **"!"** in front of a number to represent [subfactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), in particular $!4 = 9$